# Android, RelativeLayout restarts Marquee-TextView when changing ImageView in same RelativeLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, marquee

I have not found a solution for my problem, maybe you can help me here.

I am using a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and a TextView as children. The TextView contains a large text and should scroll from right to left. But everytime when I set a new image to the ImageView, the marquee starts from beginning.

I think that by setting a new image the TextView looses its focus and so the marquee starts again. How can I prevent that or is there something else I am doing wrong? Would be great if someone could point me to the correct solution.

Thanks a lot!

You can reproduce my problem with this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RelativeLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextView;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int mCurrentImage = 0;

    private Runnable mCallback = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toggleImage();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initLayout();
        setLongText();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mCallback, 5000);
    }

    private void initLayout() {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = display.getHeight();

        mImageView = new ImageView(this);
        mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth,screenHeight);        
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));
        layout.addView(mImageView, rlp);

        // marquee text at the bottom
        mTextView = new TextView(this);
        mTextView.setSingleLine();
        mTextView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        mTextView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        mTextView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        mTextView.setFocusable(true);
        mTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, 50);
        rlp.topMargin = screenHeight-100;
        layout.addView(mTextView, rlp);
    }

    private void setLongText() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            sb.append("A");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            sb.append("B");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            sb.append("C");
        }
        mTextView.setText(sb.toString());
        mTextView.setSelected(true);
    }

    private void toggleImage() {
        mCurrentImage++;
        if (mCurrentImage % 2 == 0) {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red));
        } else {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green));
        }

        mHandler.postDelayed(mCallback, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView restarts Marquee when changing another TextView in same LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856875/textview-restarts-marquee-when-changing-another-textview-in-same-linearlayout)

Answer (score 5):

I had a same problem and I fixed it just now:)

If your TextView which in layout XML contains layout_weight

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Remove it!This attibute cause marquee restart.

Hope helpful:)

Answer (score 5):

The **marquee reset problem** is because of *loss of focus* of the TextView on which it is running. To overcome these issues you can simply surround your TextView with another `RelativeLayout` so that it is in a different ViewGroup as your other views.

You have another option: Create a new class that is a subclass of TextView and override `onFocusChanged` and `onWindowFocusChanged` to prevent loss of focus for the said textview.

That's it. Using these techniques your marquee won't restart every time another element gains focus.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841982/1823503

The idea is :

- to fix the width and height programmatically (you did it)
- to setSelected (you did it)
- to Override your TextView to fix the focus problems

Comment: Hi, this did not work for me. I have added your ScrollingTextView and also added an override for "onSizeChanged", because I am on API 10. Then I have replaced my TextView with a ScrollingTextView instance and also added mTextView.setEnabled(true). But ScrollingTextView.onSizeChanged() is only called once and the marquee still restarts. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

just a simple Fix..:) no need to worry much...just fix width of textview as some 800dp or too higher width. it will solve reset issue

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/adv_txt_view"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"                               

    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"                           
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"                           
    android:focusable="true"                     
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"                       
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="large text to scroll!!" />
```